how to use force-graph in angular?
how to use force-graph in angular?
I'm trying to use force graph in angular8，but i not found angular force graph package in NPM，
I tried the following:
1、install depend
npm install d3 --save npm install  @types/d3 --save npm install force-graph --save
2、 import ForceGraph
import ForceGraph from "force-graph";
3、used in my code
this.graph = ForceGraph()(chartHtml);
However, an error was reported during compilation
ERROR in ./node_modules/force-graph/dist/force-graph.mjs 1212:94-100 Can't import the named export 'Easing' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available) ERROR in ./node_modules/force-graph/dist/force-graph.mjs 1249:40-46 Can't import the named export 'Easing' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available) ERROR in ./node_modules/force-graph/dist/force-graph.mjs 1345:22-27 Can't import the named export 'Group' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available) ERROR in ./node_modules/force-graph/dist/force-graph.mjs 1212:35-40 Can't import the named export 'Tween' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available) ERROR in ./node_modules/force-graph/dist/force-graph.mjs 1245:35-40 Can't import the named export 'Tween' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
I don't know how to solve, hope to get your help
